# Pandas - Insert specific columns from the Oracle to PostgreSql

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, oracle, dataframe

Am trying to insert the data from Oracle to PostgreSql using pandas. I have 5 columns in the source table (Oracle) and 8 columns in the target table (PostgreSql). I have a problem to insert 5 columns in a specific position in the target table. Below is my code,

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import psycopg2 as pg

OracleConnection =  cx_Oracle.connect(connection_details)
PostgreSqlConnection =  pg.connect(connection_details)

sqlOracle = pd.read_sql_query('''select salary, department, manager, name, count(1) from employees''', OracleConnection)
```

Now is have problem on inserting these values into a PosrgreSql database.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Simply specify a column list with the `INSERT`.

Comment: Can you help me on defining it in pandas

Comment: @JimMacaulay Do the 5 columns that you read from Oracle have the same name in Postgres table as well?